# GIT Clone: failed to create link Improper link on git clone

Tags: git

Using Git for Windows on powershell
Trying to clone a repository. Bare part doesnt matter. Have the same error without the "bare" option. G is a network drive within company network.
Repo is a Visual Studio asp mvc application.

```
PS G:\Folder1> git clone --bare -l 'C:\repoFolder\.git'
Cloning into bare repository 'repoFolder.git'...
fatal: failed to create link 'repoFolder.git/objects/00/6a003f1b9b6baf9c4870d54cfa1f85653e5d16': Improper link
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: `-l` will create hardlinks if possible, but that doesn't seem like it'd be desirable on a network drive. Have you tried with [`--no-hardlinks`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---no-hardlinks)?

Comment: That solved to problem. If you post it as an answer will accept it. I'm new to Git. Will switching off hardlinks pose any problems for using this clone as main repo for a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-l` will create hardlinks if possible, but that doesn't seem like it'd be desirable on a network drive. You can use [`--no-hardlinks`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---no-hardlinks) to create full copies of the object files.